# React - How many functions are recommended in the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components

I am curious about creating a component of the react.

While creating a component, the number of functions used for render() has increased.

calendar component(render()) in example.js looks like.

```
render() {

    const { isToday } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className='calendar_area'>
            <div className='calendar_header'>
                <strong className='calendar_title'>
                    <button 
                        className='btn btn-sm'
                        onClick={ this.handleTogglePrevMonth }>&lt;</button>
                    { this.createCalendarTitle() }
                    { isToday && (<button 
                        className='btn btn-sm'
                        onClick={ this.handleToggleGoToday }>
                        {/* TODO
                        select month || day === current month || today ? no show : show */}
                        Today
                    </button>) }
                    <button 
                        className='btn btn-sm'
                        onClick={ this.handleToggleNextMonth }>&gt;</button>
                </strong>
            </div>
            <div className='calendar_body'>
                <table className='calendar_table'>
                    <thead className='calendar_table_header'>
                        { this.createCalendarTableHeader() }
                    </thead>
                    <tbody className='calendar_table_body'>
                        { this.createCalendarTableBody() }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Six functions are used in render(), and functions for reuse are also created. So there are a total of eight functions.

The total number of lines excluding the import declaration, 'class ~ extends Component', and 'export default' is 165 lines, and more will be added. I want to know whether I need to create another js file to create a component, or whether I can continue writing to a single file.
Can I tell if there is a reasonable number of functions in a component?

Comment: Create as helper js file & add functions init.

Comment: @Jain make helper.js file, import and use?

Comment: Exactly, what I try to say

Comment: The decision of whether you create components out of functions that are called in render should be taken based on whether this component that you create out of the function can be reused or not at other places. If it cannot be , there is not point of moving it out into a separate component as you would be adding more overhead in passing the props and other values which in your current usecase will directly be available